# How do I link against a non-default build of GTK2?

Tags: software-installation

Firstly I'm using Rasbian on my RPi B running of a 80GB usb hard disk. My basic boot strap for any of my software is:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
svn co https://svn.code.sf.net/p/lgi/code/trunk Lgi/trunk
cd Lgi/trunk
ln -s Makefile.linux makefile
make
```

This works great on ubuntu. To build and run a simple app that uses the lib:

```
cd LgiIde
ln -s Makefile.linux makefile
make
./lgiide
```

Which then proceeds to crash fairly early on inside GTK2, overwriting the stack. This is fairly mature code that has been running well on ubuntu for ages. Having a look at the crash in gdb didn't yield anything obviously wrong in my code. And there is no valgrind to run things against. So I downloaded the GTK2 source and built it with debug turned on. Installed it to the default /usr/local position. Now I tried to rebuild LgiIde so that it picks up the new GTK2 build but it links against the old library. Here's where it gets weird, the makefile specifies the GTK headers and libs using pkg-config:

```
pi@rpi ~/Code/Lgi/trunk $ pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0
-pthread -I/usr/local/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz  

pi@rpi ~/Code/Lgi/trunk $ pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0
-L/usr/local/lib -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

So that's clearing picking up the /usr/local build, not the default release mode GTK2 installed by apt-get. However my binary still links against the apt-get libraries:

```
pi@rpi ~/Code/Lgi/trunk $ ldd Debug/liblgid.so | grep gtk
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xb6814000)
```

For reference:

```
pi@rpi ~/Code/Lgi/trunk $ find /usr -iname "*gtk-x11-2.0*"
/usr/local/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.25
/usr/local/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so
/usr/local/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.la
/usr/local/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgtk-x11-2.0.so
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.10
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgtk-x11-2.0.a
```

I'm running out of ideas here... how do I get it to link to the new GTK2?

Comment: BTW, debugging symbols are generally available in add on packages with a `-dbg` suffix.  If you `apt-cache search gtk | grep debug` you should find stuff.  `gdb` sometimes spits a note out about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folks behind raspbian did a peculiar thing.  Here's the default contents of `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`:

```
00-vmcs.conf
arm-linux-gnueabihf.conf  
libc.conf
```

When you run `ldconfig` after adding a new library to the system (you did do that, right?), links are cached by searching directories with the following precedence:

1. Anything specified on the command line.
2. List of things in `/etc/ld.so.conf`.
3. Lists of thing in files in any directories `include`d from `/etc/ld.so.conf`, which normally (including on raspbian) would be the files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` (e.g, the ones listed above).  *These are processed in lexicographical order.*
4. `/lib` and `/usr/lib`.

On Debian (derived) systems, the file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf` references `/usr/local/lib`.  What this means on a normal such system (e.g., desktop ubuntu) is that `/usr/local/lib` takes precedence over the hardcoded paths in point #4.

But the base libraries on raspbian are arranged a little oddly -- e.g., libc is actually in a non-standard location, `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`.  This and a parallel directory in `/usr/lib` are listed in the file `arm-linux-gnueabihf.conf`.<sup>1</sup>  Consequently, since that file sorts lexicographically before `libc.conf`, these standard libraries take precedence over anything in `/usr/local/lib`.

Not a very nice choice to make, since this inverts the common practice precedence on Debian.  Anyway, to fix that (as root):

```
cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d
mv arm-linux-gnueabihf.conf 20-arm-linux-gnueabihf.conf 
mv libc.conf 10-libc.conf
```

That swaps the sort order of the files.  **Now run `sudo ldconfig`** and check your executable w/ `ldd` again, you should get the link to `/usr/local/lib`.

---

<sup>1. Why that was necessary I don't know -- pidora does not do this, all the libraries are arranged normally.</sup>

Comment: That tweak works really nicely. Thanks for answering so completely. I didn't know about the ld.so.conf.d thing at all. After changing the order my app runs fine with the GTK2 that I built myself. No crash. So I don't know what the deal is with the apt-get binary.